# Сделать выборку непустых данных, исключая значения с типом данных CLOB

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Как из таблицы сделать выборку исключая null значения в столбце t1.P1 с типом данных clob?

```
select t1.t2ID, count(t1.t2ID) 
  from t1, t2
 where t1.STATUS = 2 
   and t1.t2ID = t2.ORIGINALID
   and t1.t2ID not in (select t2id 
                      from t1 
                      where status =1
                        and t2id is not null
                        and DBMS_LOB.COMPARE(t1.P1, to_clob('запись')) <> 0
                        and t1.P1 is not null)
   and DBMS_LOB.COMPARE(t1.P1, to_clob('запись')) = 0 
   and t1.P1 is not null
   and t2.ISDELETED = 0
 group by t1.t2ID 
having count(t1.t2ID) = 1;
```

Comment: И в подзапросе, и в запросе имеется соотв. условие отбора `and t1.P1 is not null`. Так в чём суть проблемы-то?

Comment: все равно выгружает данные с null значениями

Comment: *все равно выгружает данные с null значениями* Обоснуйте. Как определили? ведь значение поля `t1.P1` в выходном наборе отсутствует...

Comment: как я получаю t1.t2ID, пишу отдельный запрос: select * from t1 where t2ID = 188373885; --это например один id. Из выгруженных данных вижу, что этот t2ID имеет null значения в столбце P1. А мне нужны именно те t2ID у которых слово "запись" встречается 1 раз и не было null значений

Comment: Да? ну-ну... а СКОЛЬКО записей с этим t2ID выгружается, а? гадом буду больше одной... и из них одна имеет NOT NULL в поле, а остальные NULL. Не так ли?

Comment: @ScarlettO'Hara у вас не выгружаются null значения. Скорее всего это `emptyClob`. Добавьте уже скрипт создания таблицы и определением подя P1. Думаю, что там что-то в духе default emptyClob

Comment: В общем, убирайте `and t1.P1 is not null` из WHERE основного запроса, и добавляйте в HAVING условие `and COUNT(t1.P1) = 1`.

Comment: объем данных большой, поэтому по одному сижу и проверяю, есть ли null или нет

Comment: выходит такая ошибка: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Comment: COUNT() не хочет считать CLOB-ы? Ну воспользуйтесь тем фактом, что любая функция из DBMS_LOB при ошибке возвращает NULL. Например, используйте `and COUNT(DBMS_LOB.ISTEMPORARY(t1.P1)) = 1`. Или попробуйте почитать документацию на CLOB на предмет корректной проверки этого поля на NULL.

Comment: @Akina да там просто не `null` поле скорее всего. В оракле на `is null` все корректно проверяется, в том числе и `clob`

Comment: Я посмотрела создание таблицы, там нет написано что это empty_clob

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы проверить значение на `Null` не зависимо от типа данных используйте `is null` или `is not null`.

```
select * 
  from table 
 where clob_column_name is not null
```

Если запрос выше у вас почему то "не работает", то чаще всего это потому, что ваше поле не `null`. 
Часто при создании таблиц значение по умолчанию для колонки ставят `emptyClob`. Это пустой `clob` и не то же самое, что `null`. Чуть чуть подробнее у [Тома](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=null-clob)

Чтобы отобрать и такие значения можно проверить длину значения колонки:

```
select * 
  from table 
 where clob_column_name is not null
    or length (clob_column_name) != 0
```

иди еще можно так:

```
select * 
  from table 
 where nullif(length (clob_column_name), 0) is not null
```

Немножко подробнее по [ссылке](http://nuijten.blogspot.com/2009/11/empty-clob-is-not-null-its-not-null.html)

Comment: в моей задаче не работает, я писала

Comment: а как именно не работает? Напишите пример вашего запроса, код ошибки(или что значит не работает?) и версию oracle. Дополните этим вопрос

Comment: @ScarlettO'Hara и кусочек скрипта создания таблицы добавьте, с участком про `clob` колонку

Comment: я добавила весь запрос

Comment: версия oracle 12

Comment: @ScarlettO'Hara обновил ответ. Теперь попробуйте, должно сработать. Нет возможности проверить

Comment: @ScarlettO'Hara в результате это помогло?

Comment: запустила скрипт, но он обрабатывает уже больше часа

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93034/discussion-between-scarlett-ohara-and-viktorov).

Comment: @ScarlettO'Hara скорее всего потому, что не пустых полей у вас не особо и много. И exist у вас там какой то странный

Comment: Ок, exist поправила. Но бесконечно обрабатывает запрос

Comment: ну тут стоит план смотреть